# The Roaring Nothing Number

Tags: riddle

I'm occasionally nothing,

but I roar nonetheless,

I come in two, and sometimes six,

And I am made of four.

I am found in 60, as well as 201,

but never ever am I found in 7.

Comment: Thanks for the check mark. Out of curiosity, how close were we on the clues?

Comment: @kuhl Everything except "And I am made of four"

Comment: @kuhl That one was your first guess, `sbhe vf n snpgbe bs gjragl`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Are you

> 20

I'm occasionally nothing,  (Thanks @Riley)

> 0x20 is the [Hex code](http://www.bluesock.org/~willg/dev/ascii.html) for an ASCII Space (i.e. something) while 0x20 is 0 in mathematics (i.e. nothing).

but I roar nonetheless,

> A reference to the [roaring 20's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roaring_Twenties)

I come in two, and sometimes six,

> 20 is two characters.  Twenty is 6 characters.

And I am made of four.

> 20 is evenly divisible by 4.

I am found in 60, as well as 201,

> 60 is evenly divisible by 20, and 20 makes up the first two numbers of 201

but never ever am I found in 7.

> 7 is not evenly divisible by 20, nor is 20 a part of the numeric representation of 7.

Comment: I think "I'm occasionally nothing" may refer to the fact that 0x20 is a space in ascii.

Comment: @Riley nice catch.  Yeah, that makes sense.  Thanks!

Comment: Wait, you misinterpreted what I said. The space *is* the nothing. And 0x20 is hex for 32, not 0. Oh I see you interpreted that as multiplication. But I think the space as nothing is what was intended.

Comment: 0x00 is 0 in mathematics...

Comment: @IanMacDonald 0xanything is 0 in math.

Comment: Maybe "I am made of four" refers to [the goal](https://www.aao.org/eye-health/tips-prevention/what-does-20-20-vision-mean) of going from two to [four eyes](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/four-eyes)?

Comment: @kuhl 0x00 is hexidecimal notation, not "zero times zero". `0x10 = 16`. `0x08 = 8`. `0x0a = 10`.

Comment: @IanMacDonald I get that it's hex. x is also used as the multiplication symbol, and so 0x20 can be interpreted multiple ways. As either a hex value or to say "0 times 20".

Answer (score 12):

My best guess is

> O / 0 / "Zero"

I'm occasionally nothing,

> Used to denote the value 0

but I roar nonetheless,

> The letter 'O' still makes a sound, as in the word "roar"

I come in two, and sometimes six,

> "O" is in TW**O**, and is the bottom half of the digit version of `6`

And I am made of four.

> "ZERO" is four letters.

I am found in 60, as well as 201,

> 60 and 201 contain 0 as a digit.

but never ever am I found in 7.

> Neither 7 nor SEVEN contain an O shape.

Comment: Hmm, wrong number. But a good guess!

Comment: This was my best guess too, but I'd have been disappointed if it was the right answer. (+1 though.)

Comment: Ha, same. I threw it up here just in case

Answer (score 3):

You are number

> 3

I'm occasionally nothing,

> rotated by 180°, you get ε - used to denote infinitesimal numbers (e.g. in nonstandard analysis) or a very small number (in classical calculus)

but I roar nonetheless,

> *one, two, three, (go)* is used sometimes to count before some loud action (such as music or a car race start)

I come in two, and sometimes six,

> the glyph consists of two arcs, a prime factor of 6

And I am made of four.

> drawn in four lines in 7-segment display style

I am found in 60, as well as 201,

> a prime factor of both of these numbers

but never ever am I found in 7.

> but not a prime factor of 7

Comment: This answer uses 5 of the seven segments in a seven-segment display...

Comment: @Chowzen 5 segments, but just 4 lines - thus "style"